# Existence of a nontrivial solution to a polynomial equation

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $p \ne 0$ and consider the equation

$$ x_1 (x_1 + p)^2 + \dots + x_n (x_n + p)^2 = 0.$$

Does there exist a solution $x \in \mathbb R^n$ to this equation that is not the trivial solution $x=0$?

Comment: How about $(0, 0,\ldots, -p)$?

Comment: Any permutation of $(0, 0, 0, \dots, -p, -p, \dots, -p)$?

Comment: Fix $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-1}$ to arbitrary values you like, the condition reduces to a cubic equation in $x_n$. Since the degree of a cubic equation is odd, there is at least one real $x_n$ that satisfy the reduce cubic equation...

Answer (score 1):

According to fundamental theorem of algebra, there are at least $n$ roots in complex numbers to a polynomial of degree $n$. Some of them will be real roots, some will not.

At least one real root is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

One can obtain solutions by getting each of the individual summands to be zero: For $k\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, since $\mathbb R$ does not contain zero divisors,
$$x_k(x_k+p)^2=0$$
holds iff $x_k=0$ or $x_k+p=0$. Hence, the set of solutions is a superset of
$$\{0,-p\}^n=\{\,x\in\mathbb R^n\,\mid\,\forall k\in\{1,\dots,n\}.\;x_k\in\{0,-p\}\,\}\text.$$